# Delete attachment from SharePoint AttachmentsField Control not working

Tags: attachments, delete

I have a custom visual web part that contains a SharePoint AttachmentsField control.

```
<SharePoint:AttachmentsField ID="AttachmentsField1" ControlMode="Edit" ItemId="33"
EnableViewState="true" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/>
```

It renders the attachments correctly, and when I click on each attachment the documents are opened as desired.  However, the "delete" link next to each attachment when clicked prompts with a dialog box requesting confirmation of the attachment deletion.

I click OK, and the attachment is removed from the list, however the attachment still exsist, and once the page is refreshed the attachments still remain.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I faced same issue.. when verifying item attachments folder in SP designer I found the attachments was checked out. after discard checkout attachments  I able to delete it.