# Unable to delete list item attachment

Tags: attachments, delete

my business user was unable to delete list item attachment. He deleted the attachment while editing after save and reopen the attachment still appearing on item. I am unable to reproduce the issue in test item, even I tried with same attachment, same permissions. I found the related issue in [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58647/delete-attachment-from-sharepoint-attachmentsfield-control-not-working). Please let me know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: I fixed it. When viewed list attachments in SP designer I found the issue attachment was locked by someone. I did undo checkout and deleted attachment successfully.